# Grey area in implementing a mobile number verification system within an iOS app like snapchat/whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, messaging, whatsapp

How do applications like whatsapp and snapchat implement a mobile number verification system where users are sent text containing a unique code that is required to be inputted into the application to verify the number as being theirs? I'm interested to know what the company has setup in order for them to be able to send out text messages while its all connected with their API/Web services/application. After all, you'd never want a person sitting there sending out these texts manually :P

This is how I would go about implementing the front end on the application side:

in order of process:

1. User inputs a number claiming to be theirs and taps submit
2. application validates the number and then sends the number to I presume would be first to my web service.
3. Web service will create a random 6 digit code stored temporarily in the database for the specified number which will later be used to identify the user

   **grey area**
4. web service API some how requests for the code to be sent to the user via one of the following message senders:
5. hamsters/monkeys to send the text with code
6. webservice API creates a request message that follows strict protocol required by a marketing company where they will then handle the text sending
7. and, perhaps slightly more crazy but most likely not the way to go about it, communicates to a personally purchased network tower with a subscription to a local network that will send these texts

   **end of grey area**
8. User receives text message from mysterious sender
9. User types in code into the application
10. Application then communicates with my webservice API and says yep, the user is good to go.

Can someone please explain the grey area for me, so that I too can verify my users from my iOS application through number alone.

Comment: The API would use an [SMS gateway](https://www.google.com/search?q=sms+api+providers) like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms)

Comment: Option 6 I guess, In our company we deal with 3rd party company to handle send sms via web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 6 is closest. There are [countless SMS sending companies](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sms%20gateway%20send%20api) that have APIs/SDKs that can easily be integrated into any web app.

Comment: oh wow thats fantastic! I've been typing in keywords something similar to "sms bulk messaging" and then I never was able to find out whether the company would have an API for developers.

One thing i've learned from your search list is that an sms sending company can target numbers globally, so I dont need to search for companies from a particular region! Awesome @grahamparks thanks